# Roots of a family of polynomials forming shapes

Tags: cv.complex-variables, polynomials, statistical-physics, ising-model

Let $f$ be a smooth and strictly concave function on $[0,1]$, where $f(0)=f(1)=0$.

Let $F_n(x)=\underset{k=0}{\overset{n} \sum }  \exp(nf(\frac kn))x^k$.

The roots of $F_n$ seems to form "shapes", for example, when $f(x)=\log(1+x(1-x))$:

[image: shapes of the roots of F_n]

**Question:** Given $f$, how to find out the "shapes"?

**Motivation:** Consider a statistical mechanics model on $n$ sites, where each site can take two states. If the function $f(x)$ is the entropy per site when proportion $x$ of the sites take the first state, then the function $F_n$ is the generating function of the number of configurations with respect to the number of sites taking the first state.

Comment: How does Fn(x) depend on x? It is not in the right hand side at the moment.
If you can show that your polynomials satisfy linear recurrences, there is a lot of theory to explain the location of the roots.

Comment: The formula for $F_n$ is corrected.